# How to reserve order of values in self object in python Django

Tags: python, django

I have a python script to fetch data from db. I have to pass a list of values say names in an certain order which is required to show them on UI.
In the script these values are accessed from self object and while iteration their order changes which makes the result come wrong for each name.
My question is how to prevent the order in this case.
myPython.py script

```
class NameCollection(set):
    def __init__(self, names):
        super(NameCollection, self).__init__((Name(s) for s in names))
    def my_function(self):
       for n in self:
           names_list.append(n)
```

view.py
    from components import myPython

```
myPython.NameCollection(my_ordered_name_list)
```

Now my concern is the order of my_ordered_name_list and names_list is not same. Which is a must required thing to get the calculations right for each name.
Any help like how should the data must be accessed in these case or use any other data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets are unordered. If order is important, use a data structure that preserves it, like a list.

I'm not sure why you need to inherit from the structure, though; rather, keep the data as an instance of your class.

Comment: "keep the data as an instance of your class." Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Thanx . using the list in the collection class did the trick.